# Toggle styles on checkbox checked

Tags: html, css, checkbox, toggle

So, I've been stuck at this for a couple of hours. I'm essentially trying to get a checkbox to work as a toggle button. I want the styles applied by jquery to be only applied when it's checked and back to it's initial if it has been deselected.

The HTML markup:

```
<form class="simple_form new_mailing_list_form" data-remote="true" id="new_mailing_list_form" method="post">
  <div class="input boolean optional mailing_list_form_opt_in">
    <input name="mailing_list_form[opt_in]" type="hidden" value="0">
    <label class="boolean optional control-label checkbox toggle-button" for="mailing_list_form_opt_in">
    <input checked="checked" class="boolean optional" id="mailing_list_form_opt_in" name="mailing_list_form[opt_in]" type="checkbox" value="1">
     Yes, I would like to join the mailing list.
    </label>
 </div>
```

The SCSS:

```
#new_mailing_list_form {
.opt {
  color: $white;
  background-color: $selectiveYellow !important;
  border: 2px solid $selectiveYellow !important;
}
.checkbox {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
div label input {
  margin-right:100px;
}

.mailing_list_form_opt_in label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid $selectiveYellow;
  border-radius:2px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.4;
  overflow:auto;
  margin:4px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  width: auto;

  &:hover {
    background-color: $sunglow;
    border: 2px solid $sunglow;
    color: $white;
  }
}

.mailing_list_form_opt_in label {
  display:block;
}

.mailing_list_form_opt_in label input {
  display: none;
}

.mailing_list_form_opt_in input:checked {
  background-color:$selectiveYellow;
  color:$white;
 }
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('#mailing_list_form_opt_in').change(function () {
  $(this).parent().css({ 'background-color':'#ffbb00','border':'2px solid #ffbb00', 'color':'#fff' });
});
```

I've tried using a conditional statement as well, but I start to descend into spaghetti JQuery which doesn't even work.

Work on it so far: [Working CodePen link](http://cdpn.io/uiaBo)

Comment: @DavidThomas The linked Codepen works. And contains the exact styles & markup I have in my app.

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry, I had misunderstood your comment, I've now added it. Sorry for the misconception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm sharing my pure HTML5/CSS3 solution (which doesn't use any JS/JQuery!) to this problem so that it could be helpful for others stuck on something similar.

I refactored my markup as follows,

HTML:

```
<input id="mailing_list_form_opt_in" name="mailing_list_form[opt_in]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<label for="mailing_list_form_opt_in">Yes, I would like to join the mailing list.</label>
```

and for the styles, I used the adjacent selector `+` & the pseudo class `:checked` to show the behavior on that state. The corresponding styles for that are as follows,

SCSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid $selectiveYellow;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.4;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  @include transition( 0.25s linear);
  width: auto;

  &:hover {
    background-color: $sunglow;
    border: 2px solid $sunglow;
    color: $white;
  }
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background: $selectiveYellow !important;
  border: 2px solid $selectiveYellow !important;
  color: $white;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
```

Works perfectly, added a [Codepen](http://cdpn.io/BdxCf) so that you can check that out as well! Hope this helps others! :D

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery's `toggleClass()` method to change the background whenever a user clicks the element.

```
$("#checkbox_elem").on( "click", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass( 'background-class' );
});
```

Now all you have to do is have a default style on the element, and place the new CSS rules into the `background-class` class definition. Clicking the element will toggle the class on the element.

You could use an explicit check on the element if you want to add some more functionality:

```
$("#checkbox_elem").on( "click", function(){
  if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
    // the checkbox is marked as "checked"
    // here you can manipulate the style accordingly
  }else{
    // the checkbox is NOT marked as "checked"
    // here you can manipulate the style accordingly
  }
});
```

Comment: I had tried all of this, without success. For the answer I had to change the selector from the checkbox id to the parent label, and then toggled the background on the checked block.